# DRPaginatedScrollView - View not rendered

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Quite new to Xcode UI, I'm trying to use the nice & small pod [DRPaginatedScrollView](https://github.com/Dromaguirre/DRPaginatedScrollView).
This pod allows to scroll between multiple views.

Here is what I did

- Added a View Controller to my storyboard
- Created a `UIViewController` subclass
- Pointed my View Controller to the class
- Here is the content of my class:

```c
@implementation MyViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBoNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBoNil];
    if (self) {
        self.paginatedScrollView = [DRPaginatedScrollView new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setup];
    [self setupView];
}

- (void)setup {
    NSLog(@"Setup");
    [self.paginatedScrollView addPageWithHandler:^(UIView *pageView) {
        NSLog(@"Handler");
        UIView * square = [UIView new];
        [square setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [square setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        [pageView addSubview:square];
    }];
}

- (void)setupView {
    [self.view insertSubview:self.paginatedScrollView atIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Nb pages: [%ld]", (long)[self.paginatedScrollView numberOfPages]);
}

@end
```

My log shows only

> 2014-06-17 12:10:14.113 my_proj[6018:60b] Setup
>   2014-06-17 12:10:14.115 my_proj[6018:60b] Number of pages: [0]

My main view remains blank, "Handler" is not logged, `DRPaginatedScrollView` is counting 0 page.
Am I forgetting something ?

---

I just realized `initWithNibName` was never called (I don't understand why), so I initialized `paginatedScrollView` from `viewDidLoad`, now it's well initialized but still no render.

Answer (score 0):

I did not set `DRPaginatedScrollView`'s frame size:

```c
CGRect frameRect = self.paginatedScrollView.frame;
frameRect.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
frameRect.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
self.paginatedScrollView.frame = frameRect;
```